# JQuery - Parsexml: valid xml on one page, invalid xml on another, same xml on both

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

So this has thrown me for a loop.  I have two pages, one that I directly control, one not so much.  On both pages I am calling JQuery and loading an XML file off the page.  When I put the XML file in a javascript alert the text appears to be exactly the same.  The version of JQuery I'm using is also the same (I ran the page I don't control without the tag and it appears to not know about JQuery, so it's not being referenced anywhere else so far as I can tell).

The XML file is below.  I'm stumped as to how, under the apparent same conditions and same text, I can get two entirely different outcomes.

EDIT:  Forgot to add this is all being run from the same javascript calling the same function.  The only difference is in the pages calling, but the JQuery reference, javascript, XML, and way the XML is injected are all the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <language>ENGLISH</language>
  <showPopup>true</showPopup>
  <preventLogonOnHardFail>true</preventLogonOnHardFail>
</config>
```

Comment: for starters is this being loaded with ajax? If so is the one you don't control on a different domain (or port, subdomain etc)? Show some code and explain in more detail what happens and where

Comment: Is there other Javascript running on the page you do not control?

Comment: I'm not sure about ajax, and yes there are many, many php and javascript files being loaded all over.  I'm referencing JQuery in the header via:      <script src=\"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js\"></script>

Comment: Also just to note I'm a Windows dev, not a web dev (though I am learning a lot!), so I may not know what the hell is going on in most instances.  I'll try to answer questions as best I can though.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: To clarify and TLDR, the issue is that IE 8 reads XML files differently than versions after it, which means that the spaces that I had before the xml declaration in the file caused the reader to fail.  I removed the spaces and now everything is fine.

OK, changing the solution, got rid of the old because it doesn't matter.  The problem apparently came from a space in front of the XML declaration in the XML file.  I guess that is all it takes to trip up a XML reader...  Anyway it worked with the spaces the xml with the webpage compatibility set to IE 8, did not work on anything newer.  After removing the space the xml files load fine in anything newer, seem to hate 8.  That works for me because we're trying to get rid of dead technology anyway.

Hope this helps someone, did not think XML files could be so fragile.